# I want to use an overlay for the UIImagePickerController, but I want the shutter animation

Tags: iphone, camera

I am using the UIImagePickerController with an overlay view so I can have some custom controls.  I notice that when the user clicks the "Capture" button and I call [imagePicker takePicture], the shutter animation doesn't occur.  The effect is that I see the view sort of freeze and then continue in camera mode for a second before the image is captured and I display it over the camera view.

Make sense?

So, in other words, when the UIImagePickerController is initially presented, you see the shutter animation open up to reveal the camera, but when using overlay views and hiding camera controls, when I take the picture I don't see it.  Would really like to. :-(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently now way to do this with the built in UIImagePicker animation.  You would have to use AVFoundation and roll your own capture animation whenever you take the picture